# Using a Non-Profit org. How can I auto populate a custom email field on a different object?

Tags: nonprofit-starter-pack

I'm using a Non-Profit org and we use Soapbox which creates contact records after a client signs up.
We created a custom "Work Email" field on the Contacts and Accounts page layout (They appear as being one in the same in this Salesforce non-profit org). However, I would like to autopopulate the Opportunities record's custom Work Email field from the Contacts record custom Work Email field.
Please let me know if you need more details. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a lookup relationship between opportunity and contact by creating a lookup field on Opportunity
2. Create formula field on opportunity with return type text. For example for conatct's email write the formula: Contact__r.Email

Use Advanced Formula Tab and Insert Field button to navigate through the Lookup> field into the Contact object to insert those fields into your Opportunity Formula Fields.